# The name '' does not exist in the current context" in the same method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying make a game but I couldn't run it. The reason is because in this part:

```
if (GUI.Button(square,owner)){
    setControl(boardIndex);
}
```

the error said:

> "Error CS0103:  The name  'square' does not exist in the current
>   context" "Error CS0103:  The name  'owner' does not exist in the
>   current context" "Error CS0103:  The name  'boardIndex' does not exist
>   in the current context"

But I've already declarated before in the same method!
This is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class TicTacToeControl : MonoBehaviour {

public SquareState[] board = new SquareState[9]; 
public bool xTurn = true; //empieza X
// Use this for initialization
public void OnGUI(){
    float width = 75;
    float height = 75;

    for (int y= 0; y < 3; y++) {
        for (int x= 0; x < 3; x++) {
            int boardIndex = (y*3)+x;
            Rect square = new Rect(x *width, y*height, width, height); 
            string owner = board[boardIndex]
            == SquareState.XControl ? "X" : board[boardIndex] == SquareState.OControl ? "O" : ""; 
        }
    }

    if (GUI.Button(square,owner)){
        setControl(boardIndex);
    }

}


public void setControl(int boardIndex){  
    if (boardIndex < 0 || boardIndex >= board.Length) {
        return;
        board [boardIndex] = xTurn ? SquareState.XControl : SquareState.OControl;
        xTurn = !xTurn;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The message already mentions that `square` is not defined in that scope. However it is defined in another (deeper scope), in your loop. So you have to move that part with the `GUI` into your loop and it works.

Little side-node: The error should also occur for `owner` and `boardIndex`.

For further reading on scopes read [scopes from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

EDIT: Your code should look like this:

```
for (int y= 0; y < 3; y++) 
{
    for (int x= 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        int boardIndex = (y*3)+x;
        Rect square = new Rect(x *width, y*height, width, height); 
        string owner = board[boardIndex] == SquareState.XControl ? "X" : 
                board[boardIndex] == SquareState.OControl ? "O" : 
                ""; 

        if (GUI.Button(square,owner))
        {
            setControl(boardIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You define the square and owner variables inside the loops but then use them outside of the loops.

Either move the declarations outside of the loops or move the setControl call into the loops.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable "square" in a loop's body. You can't use the "square" outside the loop.
Try to use this code.

```
public void OnGUI(){
    float width = 75;
    float height = 75;

    for (int y= 0; y < 3; y++) {
        for (int x= 0; x < 3; x++) {
            int boardIndex = (y*3)+x;
            Rect square = new Rect(x *width, y*height, width, height); 
            string owner = board[boardIndex]
            == SquareState.XControl ? "X" : board[boardIndex] == SquareState.OControl ? "O" : ""; 
            if (GUI.Button(square,owner))
                setControl(boardIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After making variables outside the loop, your code should be like:

```
        int boardIndex;
        Rect square;
        string owner;

        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                boardIndex = (y * 3) + x;
                square = new Rect(x * width, y * height, width, height);
                owner = board[boardIndex] == SquareState.XControl ? "X" : board[boardIndex] == SquareState.OControl ? "O" : "";
            }
        }

        if (GUI.Button(square, owner))
        {
            setControl(boardIndex);
        }
```